# PDFBOX import page as form render hidden optional content group

Tags: java, pdfbox

In last version of PDFbox 2.0.27 and previous version,
when stream draw a PDFormXObject all disabled optional content group reappears.

This bug block all work with layered pdf.
There is a way to totally removed ocg ?
Do you have an idea ?

Edit :
In a new PDocument, I add this pdf with multiple ocg.

https://www.pdfill.com/example/pdf_layer_new.pdf

Result with all ocg visible (WeTransfer file available 7 days) :

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6550dcb45764d65fe96945b36e5d5b7220221010104929/2f07fd

```
PDDocument tmpPDFDocument = PDDocument.load(server.pdf());
LayerUtility utility = new LayerUtility(tmpPDFDocument);
PDFormXObject mapPDF = utility.importPageAsForm(tmpPDFDocument, 0);
stream.drawForm(form);
```

Edit 2 :

I try to clean maximum my code and after trying many times with 2.0.27,
maybe it's my fault, do you see any error here ?

Result :
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8d8f27f182c5b47bc7226acd5595dff620221011134625/97ea54

````
    public void createFile2(File output, LayoutPage layoutPage, LocalServer server) throws IOException {
        // Creation du fichier de sortie
        if (!output.exists() && !output.createNewFile())
            throw new IOException();
        // initialise le format de la page pdf
        PDRectangle box = new PDRectangle(0f, 0f, 3000, 3000);
        PDPage page = new PDPage(box);
        // creation du document pdf avec la page, le document doit rester ouvert
        // pendant toute l'impression (ignore sonar recommendation)
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        document.addPage(page);
        // initialise le context
        PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.OVERWRITE, true, true);
        PDDocument tmpPDFDocument = PDDocument.load(server.pdf()); // file url to import here
        LayerUtility utility = new LayerUtility(tmpPDFDocument);
        utility.wrapInSaveRestore(tmpPDFDocument.getPage(0));

        PDFormXObject mapPDF = utility.importPageAsForm(tmpPDFDocument, 0);
        stream.drawForm(mapPDF);
        stream.close();
        document.save(output);
        document.close();
    }
    ```
````

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, exemple was added to my post. Sorry but Snapshot doesn't resolve this bug, ocg always appears.

Comment: I found a bug in PDFBox but not the one you mentioned. I tried with 2.0.27 and it works fine. There is a display problem in PDFBox only, i.e. the files display properly in Adobe or Firefox. Either you didn't use 2.0.27 or you did something else not in the code above. Your file misses the `/OCProperties` dictionary at the top (catalog) level, this was fixed in 2017.

Comment: This is the file I created with PDFBox 2.0.27: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/13050248/PDFBOX-5524-OCGs.pdf

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, thank's for your help, but after many trying, layers always appears.
version 2.0.27, do you see an error in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct

```
LayerUtility utility = new LayerUtility(tmpPDFDocument);
```

to

```
LayerUtility utility = new LayerUtility(document);
```

LayerUtility must be initialized with the document you want to modify.

Comment: (I should have seen this in your initial code but didn't)

Comment: We didn't understand how it worked for at least three years! Thank you so much!